# The mean over the i-th row of each list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I dont find a similar question. Lets assume Ive the following list

```
a <- data.frame(number=1:10)
dat <- list(a, a*2, a*3)

   number
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
8       8
9       9
10     10

[[2]]
   number
1       2
2       4
3       6
4       8
5      10
6      12
7      14
8      16
9      18
10     20

[[3]]
   number
1       3
2       6
3       9
4      12
5      15
6      18
7      21
8      24
9      27
10     30
```

I want know to calculate the mean of each row. So the first one should be (1+2+3)/3 the 2nd one (2+4+6)/3 and so on. I think something of the apply familiy would be the right approach, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to calculate the mean of values row by row from all `data.frame`s in `dat`? Assuming all `data.frame`s have the same dimension, you can do this

```
rowMeans(data.frame(dat))
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: Would need a solution with lists since this is a very stylized example

Comment: @rook1996 `dat` *is* a `list`; simply recast as a `data.frame` and then use `rowMeans`; this works on a `list` of `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, sapply is one of the solutions.

```
a <- c(number=1:10)
dat <- list(a, a*2, a*3)
sapply(dat, function(x) mean(head(x, 3)) )



a <- data.frame(number=1:10)
dat <- list(a, a*2, a*3)
sapply(dat, function(x) mean(head(x[,1], 3)) )
```

Comment: Getting an error on it

Comment: that is because, data is data.frame, edited answer